Network cant be reached in any way with weird apparmor behavior
I compile apparmor from sourc 4.0.0~alpha2-0ubuntu5 amd64, and was trying compile too gui apparmor https://github.com/jack-ullery/AppAnvil, and it's weird becouse i turned off and disable with systemctl stop apparmor, and reboot lot of time, but still cant access internet, ping anything, apt update and check each setting of network from virtualbox with all adapters. NAT, nat network, host-only, internal, bridged and cant reach internet in any ways, but logs in kern.log are weird, are those profiles and even turning off apparmor, still make notification when i try apt update, i disable all profiles with one single command sudo apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/* and belive me i systemctl stop apparmor. Maybe there is some other /etc/apparmor.d with loaded profiles when i compile from source apparmor, it can be? After i execute command to disable all profiles i get those line output. I dont know how to disable fully those profiles deny'ing something in log and notification even with turned off and trying disabling those profiles, and system treat them like their notexisting, but they are in /etc/apparmor.d/... Or maybe its diffrent problem really and cant figure out. Please help me becouse it's happy me much, and im really good person, just drop some ideas what it cant be. I checked ubuntu desktop in virtual box with random NAT and one adapter and can reach internet, ssh to windows laptop, even kali laptopt, ping addresses even 10.2.0.0 to 192.168.1.87. That things i already did on my windows system and kali linux or put some iptable rules for accept and establish tcp connectiom on 22 port in my ubuntu server 22 where are those problem in each network setting.
I have already configured my firewall router and set it to accept connections and port forwarding, I also set port forwarding in the nat network option in virutalbox, I turned on the options in Windows advanced options with file and sharing for icmp request and also for core diagnostics monitoring, I ran it in services openssh and ssh agent for ssh connections, remote desktop connection tool works, I used the command on Linux "sudo iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT", I turned off the firewall for my network and the antivirus, I changed wifi profile in windows on private, i check tool's fing for windows to networking and diagnostic, they work well all devices connected to wifi, after enabling Get-Command New-PSSession.ParameterSets.Name in powershell, I do not have visible SSHost and SSHHostHashParam, I used the commands on windows, I installed Install-Module -Name Posh-SSH in powershell, checked ssh to demo@test.rebex.net, updated windows update, even got new drivers for wifi firmware, used Inter-Driver-and-support-assistance, amd -software-adrenaline-edition, geforce expierence and windows updates, I edited bind9 correctly, entering the addresses of the Ubuntu server, Windows, Kali in the ACL list, I also entered the nameserver of my DNS that I want to use, I checked the operation of the networkmanager, sudo dhclient -v enp0s3 cannot be used either finish.
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         UG    20100  0        0 enp0s3
10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp0s3
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.8.0.2        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp0s3
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:b5:df:44 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp0s3
       valid_lft 83936sec preferred_lft 83936sec
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:feb5:df44/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
    link/none 
    inet 10.8.0.1 peer 10.8.0.2/32 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::2a8d:c7dd:ea2:472e/64 scope link stable-privacy 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:31:fe:86:12 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever


AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abi in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abi/3.0 at line 1: syntax error, unexpected TOK_OPEN, expecting TOK_MODE
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abi in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abi/4.0 at line 1: syntax error, unexpected TOK_CAPABILITY, expecting end of file
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abi in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abi/kernel-5.4-outoftree-network at line 1: syntax error, unexpected TOK_OPEN, expecting TOK_MODE
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abi in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abi/kernel-5.4-vanilla at line 1: syntax error, unexpected TOK_OPEN, expecting TOK_MODE
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/dri-common at line 8: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/nameservice at line 18: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/aspell at line 7: syntax error, unexpected TOK_OWNER, expecting end of file
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/audio at line 16: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/authentication at line 19: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/crypto at line 16: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/bash at line 14: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_EQUALS or TOK_ADD_ASSIGN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/consoles at line 16: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/crypto at line 16: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/cups-client at line 15: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/dbus-strict at line 14: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/dbus-accessibility-strict at line 14: syntax error, unexpected TOK_DBUS, expecting end of file
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/dbus-accessibility-strict at line 14: syntax error, unexpected TOK_DBUS, expecting end of file
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/dbus-network-manager-strict at line 5: syntax error, unexpected TOK_DBUS, expecting end of file
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/dbus-session-strict at line 15: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/dbus-session-strict at line 15: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/dbus-strict at line 14: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/dconf at line 8: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/dovecot-common at line 14: syntax error, unexpected TOK_CAPABILITY, expecting end of file
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/dri-common at line 8: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/dri-enumerate at line 9: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/enchant at line 16: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/crypto at line 16: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/dri-common at line 8: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/dbus-session-strict at line 15: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/dbus-session-strict at line 15: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/fonts at line 15: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/freedesktop.org at line 15: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/crypto at line 16: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/crypto at line 16: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/gnupg at line 7: syntax error, unexpected TOK_OWNER, expecting end of file
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/groff at line 17: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/crypto at line 16: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/gtk at line 12: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/crypto at line 16: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/hosts_access at line 14: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/ibus at line 15: syntax error, unexpected TOK_OWNER, expecting end of file
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/crypto at line 16: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/kde-globals-write at line 8: syntax error, unexpected TOK_OWNER, expecting end of file
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/kde-icon-cache-write at line 8: syntax error, unexpected TOK_OWNER, expecting end of file
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/kde-language-write at line 11: syntax error, unexpected TOK_OWNER, expecting end of file
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/audio at line 16: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/kerberosclient at line 15: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/ldapclient at line 14: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/dbus-strict at line 14: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/likewise at line 14: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/mdns at line 14: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/mesa at line 7: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/mir at line 16: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/mozc at line 14: syntax error, unexpected TOK_UNIX, expecting end of file
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/mysql at line 14: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/nameservice at line 18: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/nis at line 14: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/nss-systemd at line 22: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/nvidia at line 7: syntax error, unexpected TOK_CAPABILITY, expecting end of file
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/opencl-common at line 9: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/opencl-common at line 9: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/opencl-common at line 9: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/opencl-common at line 9: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/nvidia at line 7: syntax error, unexpected TOK_CAPABILITY, expecting end of file
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/opencl-common at line 9: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/openssl at line 13: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/orbit2 at line 7: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/p11-kit at line 13: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/perl at line 15: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/php at line 16: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/crypto at line 16: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/php at line 16: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/postfix-common at line 17: syntax error, unexpected TOK_CAPABILITY, expecting end of file
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/private-files at line 9: syntax error, unexpected TOK_DENY, expecting end of file
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/private-files at line 9: syntax error, unexpected TOK_DENY, expecting end of file
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/python at line 15: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/qt5 at line 8: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/qt5-compose-cache-write at line 8: syntax error, unexpected TOK_OWNER, expecting end of file
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/qt5-settings-write at line 8: syntax error, unexpected TOK_OWNER, expecting end of file
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/recent-documents-write at line 8: syntax error, unexpected TOK_OWNER, expecting end of file
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/ruby at line 14: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/samba at line 14: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/crypto at line 16: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/smbpass at line 15: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
Found reference to variable HOME, but is never declared
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/ssl_certs at line 14: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/ssl_keys at line 18: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/svn-repositories at line 19: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/crypto at line 16: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/trash at line 5: syntax error, unexpected TOK_OWNER, expecting end of file
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/ubuntu-bittorrent-clients at line 11: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/ubuntu-browsers at line 11: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/ubuntu-console-browsers at line 15: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/ubuntu-console-email at line 15: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/ubuntu-email at line 11: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/ubuntu-feed-readers at line 11: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/crypto at line 16: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
Found reference to variable run, but is never declared
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/consoles at line 16: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/ubuntu-media-players at line 11: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/crypto at line 16: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/ubuntu-unity7-launcher at line 6: syntax error, unexpected TOK_DBUS, expecting end of file
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/ubuntu-unity7-messaging at line 7: syntax error, unexpected TOK_DBUS, expecting end of file
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/consoles at line 16: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/user-download at line 17: syntax error, unexpected TOK_OWNER, expecting end of file
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/user-mail at line 15: syntax error, unexpected TOK_OWNER, expecting end of file
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/user-manpages at line 15: syntax error, unexpected TOK_OWNER, expecting end of file
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/user-tmp at line 15: syntax error, unexpected TOK_OWNER, expecting end of file
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/user-write at line 15: syntax error, unexpected TOK_OWNER, expecting end of file
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/video at line 7: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/vulkan at line 7: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/wayland at line 14: syntax error, unexpected TOK_OWNER, expecting end of file
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/web-data at line 14: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/winbind at line 15: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/wutmp at line 16: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/xad at line 13: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/xdg-desktop at line 17: syntax error, unexpected TOK_OWNER, expecting end of file
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions in profile /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/crypto at line 16: syntax error, unexpected TOK_MODE, expecting TOK_OPEN
Found reference to variable run, but is never declared
apparmor_parser: Unable to remove "ping".  Profile doesn't exist
apparmor_parser: Unable to remove "/bin/toybox".  Profile doesn't exist
apparmor_parser: Unable to remove "ping".  Profile doesn't exist
apparmor_parser: Unable to remove "/usr/sbin/sssd".  Profile doesn't exist
apparmor_parser: Unable to remove "/home/test.py".  Profile doesn't exist
apparmor_parser: Unable to remove "lsb_release".  Profile doesn't exist
apparmor_parser: Unable to remove "nvidia_modprobe".  Profile doesn't exist
apparmor_parser: Unable to remove "/opt/brave.com/brave/brave".  Profile doesn't exist
apparmor_parser: Unable to remove "/opt/google/chrome/chrome".  Profile doesn't exist
apparmor_parser: Unable to remove "/opt/microsoft/msedge/msedge".  Profile doesn't exist
apparmor_parser: Unable to remove "/opt/vivaldi/vivaldi-bin".  Profile doesn't exist
apparmor_parser: Unable to remove "php-fpm".  Profile doesn't exist
apparmor_parser: Unable to remove "samba-bgqd".  Profile doesn't exist
apparmor_parser: Unable to remove "samba-dcerpcd".  Profile doesn't exist
apparmor_parser: Unable to remove "samba-rpcd".  Profile doesn't exist
apparmor_parser: Unable to remove "samba-rpcd-classic".  Profile doesn't exist
apparmor_parser: Unable to remove "samba-rpcd-spoolss".  Profile doesn't exist
apparmor_parser: Unable to remove "/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action".  Profile doesn't exist
apparmor_parser: Unable to remove "klogd".  Profile doesn't exist
apparmor_parser: Unable to remove "syslogd".  Profile doesn't exist
apparmor_parser: Unable to remove "syslog-ng".  Profile doesn't exist
apparmor_parser: Unable to remove "/usr/bin/buildah".  Profile doesn't exist
apparmor_parser: Unable to remove "/usr/bin/busybox".  Profile doesn't exist
apparmor_parser: Unable to remove "/usr/bin/cam".  Profile doesn't exist
apparmor_parser: Unable to remove "/usr/bin/ch-checkns".  Profile doesn't exist
apparmor_parser: Unable to remove "/usr/bin/ch-run".  Profile doesn't exist
apparmor_parser: Unable to remove "/usr/bin/crun".  Profile doesn't exist
apparmor_parser: Unable to remove "/usr/bin/evince".  Profile doesn't exist
apparmor_parser: Unable to remove "/usr/bin/flatpak".  Profile doesn't exist
apparmor_parser: Unable to remove "/usr/bin/freshclam".  Profile doesn't exist
apparmor_parser: Unable to remove "/usr/bin/ipa_verify".  Profile doesn't exist
apparmor_parser: Unable to remove "/usr/bin/irssi".  Profile doesn't exist
apparmor_parser: Unable to remove "/usr/bin/lc-compliance".  Profile doesn't exist
apparmor_parser: Unable to remove "/usr/bin/libcamerify".  Profile doesn't exist
apparmor_parser: Unable to remove "/usr/bin/lxc-attach".  Profile doesn't exist

